# if data is exist in gridview then don't show the data in the dropdownlist in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, drop-down-menu

simply i want to hide data in the dropdownlist if this data is exist in gridview

i have gridview that get the datas from database
first data of gridview is "book name".

For example book name is book1

I listed book's name in dropdown list. User is select the book name in the dropdown list and press add button . when user add  book1, book1 is written into database and then shown into the gridview , after that in dropdown list, book1 shouldn't appear anymore.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDergi" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="DERGI_ADI" DataValueField="DERGI_ADI">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbTek" Text="Tek Sefer" Checked="true" GroupName="secim" runat="server" /><asp:RadioButton ID="rbSurekli" Text="Sürekli" GroupName="secim" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnTalep" runat="server" Text="Talep Et" OnClick="btnTalep_Click" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BOOKConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [DERGI_ADI] FROM [DERGILER]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="KULLANICI_ADI" HeaderText="KULLANICI ADI" SortExpression="KULLANICI_ADI" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DERGI_ADI" HeaderText="DERGI ADI" SortExpression="DERGI_ADI" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TEK" HeaderText="TEK" SortExpression="TEK" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SUREKLI" HeaderText="SUREKLI" SortExpression="SUREKLI" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BOOKConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DERGILER.DERGI_ADI, BAGLANTI.TEK, BAGLANTI.SUREKLI, KULLANICILAR.KULLANICI_ADI FROM BAGLANTI INNER JOIN DERGILER ON BAGLANTI.DERGI_ADI = DERGILER.DERGI_ADI INNER JOIN KULLANICILAR ON BAGLANTI.KULLANICI_ADI = KULLANICILAR.KULLANICI_ADI ">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

DERGI_ADI is our bookname

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: You can use RowBound event of gridview to check and remove an item from drop down list,if it exists in the Grid. Or opposite is also possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195964/how-can-i-hide-empty-columns-in-a-gridview-without-knowing-which-will-be-empty

Comment: can I have some code here

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would probably do it.

```
if(gvGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   ddlDropDownList.Items.Remove("Book1");
}
```

And it sounds like you will want to have it on the drop down list with SelectedIndexChanged event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help. But there is not certain item that is may be book1 may be book2 etc. Therefore i want to read gridview first columns and then if it is exist that data should not shown in dropdown list

Comment: You should still be able to adapt the above code to fit your needs. But without showing any code, it's pretty hard to tell you exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one:

```
if(gvGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   foreach(GridViewRow row in gvGridView1.Rows)
    {
            ListItem li;
            li.Text = row.Cells[1].Text; // you need to identify column number
            li.Value =row.Cells[1].Text;// you need to identify column number
            if ( ddlDropDownList.Items.Contains(li)==true)
            {
                ddlDropDownList.Items.Remove(li);
            }

        }
}
```